# React-Native: How do I render a list of markers from firebase on Airbnb maps?

Tags: components, react-native, react-native-maps

I am a beginner to react-native and am currently trying to get markers from a firebase database and render them onto my map. I had previously defined the markers as `markers: []` and filled the markers object with dummy objects (the exact same object I retrieve from the firebase database).

I define the initial `markers` object within the state variable.

```
 markers: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      })
```

And finally render this using `ListView` from react-native

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.markers}
    renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
>
</ListView>
```

With _renderItem being defined as follows:

```
_renderItem(marker) {
    console.log(marker);
    return (
      <MapView.Marker
      coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}
      title={marker.description}
      description={marker.description}>
      <View style={styles.bikeRadius}>
             <View style={styles.bikeMarker}></View>
      </View>
      </MapView.Marker>
    );
  }
```

I can render specific properties of the object, if I set the `return` value of `_renderItem` to `<Text> {marker.description} </Text>`.

You will find the full code on CodePen: https://codepen.io/yeni/pen/BZjJYq

The markers don't render at all. Furthermore, after implementing the `<ListView>` component I cannot move or zoom on the map any further. Any ideas how to incorporate markers from Firebase on AirBnb MapView.Markers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a ListView, you can simply map over your markers inside the `MapView`:

```
<MapView>
  {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
    <MapView.Marker
      coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}
      title={marker.description}
      description={marker.description}>
      <View style={styles.bikeRadius}>
        <View style={styles.bikeMarker}></View>
      </View>
    </MapView.Marker>
  )}
<MapView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift answer! :) Unfortunately, when I try this function, it says 'this.state.markers.map' is not a function. I assume this is because I have a ListView object?

Comment: Totally. You must have an array.

Comment: So, I can successfully let markers disappear, but when I change a conditional property in the code, it doesn't re-appear.. Any idea what might be wrong? I added a 50 bounty on this if you're interested :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699115/react-native-airbnb-markers-markers-successfully-disappear-but-do-not-re-appea